# Making Terminal recognize HandBrakeCLI commands

Tags: video-editing

I just downloaded HandBrake on my Mac to edit videos (and compress them).

The GUI works fine, however, when I type the command HandBrakeCLI in Terminal, it does NOT find the command.

The specific issue I am trying to resolve is that I want Terminal to know where to find the HandBrakeCLI commands and related tools.

How do I do that once I have a working GUI?

How do you "activate" the HandBrakeCLI command on MAC?

This is what I am typing into my terminal:

```
username~ $ HandBrakeCLI -h
-bash: HandBrakeCLI: command not found
```

I got the idea to type that command from:

https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide

Comment: What command are you typing exactly? Have you read [this page](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide) first?

Comment: any command basically.

Comment: Any command? Please edit your question with what you're typing into your terminal app so we can know if there's anything faulty with your input, or if the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I did read it. But didn't say how to make bash know where it is. I guess I should phrase my question better but what I meant was, once you have downloaded it, how do you make your terminal know where to find it as a command tool?

Comment: @zerohedge you are right, I apologize, I didn't realize what else to add. I have improved my question. Does the problem make sense now?

Comment: It's OK :) does my answer below cover it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded the [command line version](https://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php)?

From [HandBrake's CLIGuide](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide):

> tell the shell to look for the program in the current working
>   directory. To run a command in the Terminal, you just type its name.
>   But the shell will only look in the places where applications are
>   usually stored (like /usr/bin/). You need to tell it to look in the
>   current directory. To do that, precede the program name with `./` like
>   this:
>
> `./HandBrakeCLI`
>
> Of course, running that won't do much anything useful. If you run
>   HandBrake without telling it what to do, it will just tell you to read
>   the help...

**Or**: Instructions on [how to compile Handbrake in OS X](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CompileGuide), probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes that definitively helps me try something. However, its weird, HandBrakeCLI is in neither of those folders... :S

Comment: I wonder if I can just brew install it...

Comment: See my edit at the end of the answer.

Comment: that guide is really not helpful. I want to call `HandBrakeCLI` not provide the full path each time. Also the last link is dead.